# Why is my number coming up as an object when passed in the prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a component `FooterScroll`. And the main page is `TvIndex`.

> This is the **FooterScroll** Component

```
const FooterScroll = (Id: number) => {
  const { event } = useEvent(Id);
  console.log('Id', Id);

  return (
    <Marquee speed={85}>
      <Grid container>
        {event?.notices.map((notice: EventNotice) => {
          if (notice.approved) {
            return (
              <>
                <Grid item px={4} key={notice.id}>
                  <CampaignIcon />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item alignItems="center">
                  {notice.body}
                </Grid>
              </>
            );
          }
        })}
      </Grid>
    </Marquee>
  );
};

export default FooterScroll;
```

> This is the **TvIndex** Page

```
  import FooterScroll from 'components/pages/members/tv/scrolling-footer';

  const TvIndex: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.scrollFooter}>
        <FooterScroll Id={39324} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TvIndex;
```

For some reasons that I don't understand, when I pass in this any id number as a prop in my main component for `FooterScroll`, it gives me this error: *`Type '{Id: number;}' is not assignable to type 'number'`*.
Then I decided to console log it inside `FooterScroll`, and it looks like after the id gets passed in `TvIndex`, it passes inside the `FooterScroll` component as an Object, like so: `Id > Object { Id: 39324 }`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The argument passed to a React component is an *object*, whose properties are the props passed down by the caller. For example

```
<FooterScroll Id={39324} />
```

results in a prop object of:

```
{
  Id: 39324
}
```

React doing it this way allows for easily adding additional props, or properties to the `props` object, without changing the function signature much:

```
<FooterScroll Id={39324} someOtherProp="foo" />
```

results in a prop object of:

```
{
  Id: 39324,
  someOtherProp: 'foo'
}
```

So, you need to change the function definition to

```
const FooterScroll = ({ Id }: { Id: number }) => {
```

or do

```
const FooterScroll = (props: { Id: number }) => {
  const { Id } = props;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to the `FooterScroll` are wrong. Try this:

```
  const FooterScroll = ({ Id }: { Id: number }) => {
  ...
  }
```

It should work.

Comment: looks like autocorrect struck

Comment: Right, answering from the phone sucks :)